# When there is no data on CSV, It is causing error. How can I avoid this error, Javascript

Tags: javascript, csv, quickbase

I am very new to Javascript

This Javascript code moves CSV files to Quickbase on Windows Script Host. so I get the data every one hour from Microsoft Azure to these CSV,

I made autoflow from Azure to CSV using powershell and task scheduler, these CSV files to QUickbase by using this Javascript code/Task Schduler

However, when there is no data on CSV file/CSV file is empty. this code causes the error.

but I would just move the CSV data as empty to QuickBase Table without causing Error.

How should I change the code?

```
var datafile = "3-Month Free Trial-SQLDataServer.csv";
var dbid = "beegbjn3e2";
var username = "useranme";
var password = "Helloworld";
var subdomain = "Mycompany";                                                               


var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var csv = fso.OpenTextFile(datafile, 1).ReadAll();
fso.close;

    WScript.Echo(csv);

    var url = "";
    url += "https://" + subdomain + ".quickbase.com/db/" + dbid;
    url += "?act=API_ImportFromCSV";
    url += "&username=" + username;
    url += "&password=" + password;

    WScript.Echo(url);

    var request = "";
    request += "<qdbapi>";
    request += "<skipfirst>1</skipfirst>";
    request += "<records_csv><![CDATA[";
    request += csv;
    request += "]]></records_csv>";
    request += "</qdbapi>";
    WScript.Echo(request); 

    var xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    xmlhttp.open("POST", url, false);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("content-type","text/xml");
    xmlhttp.send(request);
    WScript.Echo(xmlhttp.responseText);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var namestart = fso.OpenTextFile(datafile, 1);

var name2 = namestart.AtEndOfStream ? "" : namestart.ReadAll();


{

 var url = "";
 url += "https://" + subdomain + ".quickbase.com/db/" + dbid;
 url += "?act=API_ImportFromCSV";
 url += "&username=" + username;
 url += "&password=" + password;

 WScript.Echo(url);

 var request = "";
 request += "<qdbapi>";
 request += "<skipfirst>1</skipfirst>";
 request += "<records_csv><![CDATA[";
 request += name2;
 request += "]]></records_csv>";
 request += "</qdbapi>";
 WScript.Echo(request); 

 var xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
 xmlhttp.open("POST", url, false);
 xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("content-type","text/xml");
 xmlhttp.send(request);
 WScript.Echo(xmlhttp.responseText);
}
namestart.Close();
```